# Intel Pin Tool permission error

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, instrumentation, intel-pin

The following works fine and I get the edgecnt out from 'ls' program on my ubuntu 14.04 system..

```
$ ../../../pin.sh -t obj-intel64/edgcnt.so -- /bin/ls
```

but while using it on my node application I got permission denied error:

```
$ ../../../pin.sh -t obj-intel64/edgcnt.so -- /home/samira/Documents/benchmarks/lets-chat/
/home/samira/Documents/benchmarks/lets-chat/ : Permission denied
```

I searched all the web about that but I haven't found any solution. I tried runing both node application and pin tool as root but it didn't solve the problem. Also used the pid to run:

```
s# ../../../pin -pid 14191 -t obj-intel64/edgcnt.so -o myout.log
E: Could not attach to process 14191: need execute and read access to /proc/14191/exe
```

I tried to change the permission of /proc/ folder but the operation was not permitted even for the root.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while using pin on your node application,got permition denied,have you change the user group?

as a root,"root@server:~# echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope"
may help your question.

"s# ../../../pin -pid 14191 -t obj-intel64/edgcnt.so -o myout.log
E: Could not attach to process 14191: need execute and read access to /proc/14191/exe"  I think this means the pid you want to trace doesn't exsist.